# Angular - multiple promises wrapped in one promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a couple of services that return the same type of objects just a different type via a flag on the object.  These services have functions that return a promise.

Service 1 - getPlaces:

```
this.getPlaces = function () {
            return $http.get('http://somewhere.com').then(function (response) {
                    return response;
     }).catch(exception.catcher('Something went wrong'));
};
```

Service 2 - getPlaces:

```
this.getPlaces = function () {
            return $http.get('http://somewhere.com/').then(function (response) {
                    return response;
     }).catch(exception.catcher('Something went wrong'));
};
```

What I also have is a wrapper Service that calls both of these services and I don't want the function in the service wrapper to return the combined results until both promises fully executed and returned results (or null).  I'm currently doing it the following way:

```
    this.getCombinedResults = function () {
        var combined= [];

        var apiCalls = [service1.getPlaces(), service2.getPlaces()];

        $q.all(apiCalls.map(function(call) {
            return call;
        })).then(function (response) {
            angular.forEach(response, function (item, index) {
                combined.push(item);
            });
        });            
        return combined;
    };
```

Is this the correct way of wrapping multiple promises in a promise?  If not what should change.  I don't think it's working correctly, particularly in my wrapper service.  When calling the wrapper service function it returns null.

I'm going to look into this more but if I can get a heads up as to whether what I'm writing is correct would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `getCombinedResults` is calling a promise based service, this service too should return a promise, else combined will always be empty.

Just do

```
 return $q.all(apiCalls.map(function(call) {
            return call;
        })).then(function (response) {
            angular.forEach(response, function (item, index) {
                combined.push(item);
            });
            return combined;
        });
```

Because `then` too returns a promise, this code will return a promise back to caller.

The resolved value would be `combined`.

Also in the calling code you need to use promise based resolution of response using `then`.

Comment: I actually just spotted this in my code after posting on stackoverflow.  Getting a new error - Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: It's all good, I forgot the return on my $q.all.  I feel silly now.  Is what I have done the correct way of doing it?  I probably shouldn't be returning promises all the way through my architecture?  But if I didn't do that how could I wrap multiple calls in a $q.all - do they have to be promises?

Comment: Yes, believe. You can use `$q.when(value)` to wrap non promise based data.